# Log a list of files and open them with VSCode CLI

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a macro on my shell.

The operation I'm trying to automate is this one:

```
Find all the files containing TEXT_TO_SEARCH, and open them with VSCODE
```

I can do this with a one-liner

```bash
$ code `git grep TEXT_TO_SEARCH | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`
```

so my first step was adding the following function to `~/.zshrc`

```bash
cgrep() {
  code `git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`
}
```

and then

```bash
$ cgrep TEXT_TO_SEARCH
```

This works.

Now I'm trying to add an extra feature:

```
Before opening each file with VSCode, echo to the console "Opening FILE_NAME"
```

First I've tryied this

```bash
cgrep() {
  grep_results=`git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`
  for file in $grep_results; do
    echo "Opening $file"
    code $file
  done
}
```

Note that `grep_results` is a "vertical list" i.e.

```bash
$ echo $grep_results

src/path1/FILE1.py
src/path2/FILE2.py
src/path3/FILE3.py
```

This way the for loop considers the first `file` as the whole `grep_results` and it opens `FILE3.py` (not `src/path3/FILE3.py`).

I've also tryied this (with the help of GPT)

```bash
cgrep() {
  grep_results=`git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`
  echo "$grep_results" | while read -r file; do
    echo "Opening $file"
    code "$file"
  done
}
```

This way I can open just the first grepped file, and I get a message I don't want from VSCode and I don't actually understand

```bash
$ cgrep TEXT_TO_SEARCH

Opening src/path1/FILE1.py
Run with 'code -' to read from stdin (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -').
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git grep TEXT_TO_SEARCH | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`

You can simplify this to

```
git grep -l TEXT_TO_SEARCH
```

You don't need the sorting step since the list won't include the same file name multiple times, and `git grep` (unlike `grep -r`) produces a sorted list in practice.

> `` grep_results=`git grep …` ``

You're putting a list of file names in a string. Use an [array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters) instead. The input is a newline-separated list, so tell zsh that (by default it would treat spaces, tabs and nuls as separators as well, which would break with file names containing spaces or tabs), using the `f` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
grep_results=( ${(f)"$(git grep -l -- TEXT_TO_SEARCH)"} )
```

You can make that code work with newlines in file names (which may or may not matter in your case). Tell `git grep` to use null bytes to separate list elements, and zsh to split the output at null bytes.

```
grep_results=( ${(0)"$(git grep -lz -- TEXT_TO_SEARCH)"} )
```

Now that you have the file names in an array, just iterate over the array.

```
for file in $grep_results; do
  print -r Opening $file
  code -- $file
done
```

---

> I get a message I don't want from VSCode and I don't actually understand

At a guess, `code` emits this message when it notices that its standard input is a pipe but it sees a file name on its command line. If that's the case, you could get rid of it by running `code </dev/null "$file"`, so that `code`'s standard input is not a pipe.

Comment: Yup, your guess in the last paragraph is correct.

Comment: My fault  Thank you @Gilles

Comment: Just one tiny correction I had to make `for file in "${grep_results[@]}";`. Again, thank you very much

Comment: @chc `for file in $grep_results` is equivalent and simpler. It doesn't work in bash, only in zsh, but my whole answer is about zsh, not bash.

Comment: Strictly speaking `$grep_results` is not the same as `"${grep_result[@]}"` in that it discards empty elements (which here is probably a good thing). Empty elements cannot occur here as `${(f)"$(...)"}` or `${(0)"$(...)"}` would have discarded empty records already.